# Copy method of Range class failed

Tags: excel, vba, copy, runtime-error

I'm trying to copy the entire contents of one Sheet (which is user-inputted) to another Sheet (which is hidden, but not protected).  When I run it, I get the error: Run-time error '1004': Copy method of Range class failed.

This is my code:

```
Sub CopyDataToTable()
    Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
    Dim targetSheet As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim lastColumn As Long
    Dim sourceRange As Range
    Dim targetCell As Range

    ' Set the source and target sheets
    Set sourceSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Report Data")
    Set targetSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ReportAsTable")

    ' Find the last row and last column with data in the source sheet
    lastRow = sourceSheet.Cells(sourceSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    lastColumn = sourceSheet.Cells(1, sourceSheet.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    ' Set the source range excluding the header row
    Set sourceRange = sourceSheet.Range(sourceSheet.Cells(2, 1), sourceSheet.Cells(lastRow, lastColumn))

    ' Set the target cell where you want to paste the data in the target sheet
    Set targetCell = targetSheet.Cells(2, 1)
    
    ' Copy the data from the source range to the target cell
    sourceRange.Copy targetCell
    
    ' Clear the clipboard
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

When I press Debug, it highlights this line:

```
    sourceRange.Copy targetCell
```

If I un-hide the Sheet "ReportAsTable" and navigate to it, then run the code, it works without issue.

I tried adding a step to Activate the target Sheet before the Copy, with this:

```
    targetSheet.Range("A2").Select
```

but, it still throws the same error.

Comment: BTW, in regards to *"... but, it still throws the same error."*, look closer: It's a different error (description) i.e. you have to make sure that the sheet is active (`targetSheet.Activate`) before you can select a cell on it. `Application.CutCopyMode = False` is redundant after using the *[Copy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.copy)* method with a *Destination* parameter.

Comment: Even with this: (targetSheet.Activate) I still get the exact same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everyone who took the time to offer suggestions.  I'm not sure why this made it work, but it did and I wouldn't have gotten it without y'all.

For some reason, Activating the target sheet, then back to the sheet that holds the buttons made it stop throwing the error.  Here's what I ended up using:

```
    targetSheet.Visible = xlSheetVisible
    targetSheet.Activate
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Start Here").Activate
    sourceRange.Copy targetCell
    targetSheet.Visible = xlSheetHidden
```

If anyone has any idea why that was needed, I'd love to learn from ya.  Either way, I'm just glad it's working now.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Try using these lines instead of activating the target sheet:

```
    ' Copy the data from the source range to the target cell
    Sheets("ReportAsTable").Visible = xlSheetVisible
    sourceRange.Copy targetCell
    Sheets("ReportAsTable").Visible = xlSheetHidden
```

btw, the code works perfectly to me without this adjustment.

Comment: What version of Excel are you all using?

Comment: I continue to get the same error on the same line: `sourceRange.Copy targetCell`

Comment: I'm using: Excel for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2401 Build 16.0.17231.20194) 64-bit